# How to set up attributes for products with ACF Pro and Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I wanna to make a catalog of different equipment and I'm a little bit stuck.

Here is a great example I'm orienting to: ritchiespecs.com/model/jcb-413s-ht-hl-wheel-loader
As you can see models on this website have specifications grouped by categories, and each category has it's subgroup with characteristics inside.

Besides, each charateristic has separate value and unit of measurement.

I wonder is it possible to do with ACF Pro and Woocommerce? And how I possibly can create an import file for it, so that I get the right hierarchy of groups, subgroups and characteristics? Also I don't know the exact amount of groups, subgroups and characteristics, will it be possible to automatically create such terms in ACF Pro using WP All Import plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Good day Aleksey.
Yes you can create custom fields with ACF for each of characteristic.
But the problem is to import all them to DataBase.
I mean needsome automatization to compare each value to the key.

Do you want all the sub-Categories?[image]

Comment: Yeah, I want all these sub-categories on my website, but I don't know how to implement it.